# I need to get an exact match on this PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in a plugin in Wordpress, it creates tables in MySQL and store data in then I get it with search page, this page has a search form and its supposed to search with id but the problem is that when I click submit 0 in the search form it's got all results to start with 0
but I need it to work with an exact match

```
function ghazale_sds_front_end_search_field( $atts ) {
    $output = '<form id="sds-search-entries" method="post">';
    $output .= '<h3>' . __( 'Search', 'custom-searchable-data-entry-system' ) . ':</h3>';
    $output .= '<p><input required type="number"  name="sds-search-data" size="9" placeholder="' . __( 'Patient ID', 'custom-searchable-data-entry-system' ) . ' "  autocomplete="off" ></p>';




    $output .= '<p><input type="submit" name="submit-sds-search-query" value="' . __( 'Search', 'custom-searchable-data-entry-system' ) . '"></p></br>';
    $output .= '</form>';



    if ( isset( $_POST['submit-sds-search-query'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $tables       = $wpdb->prefix . "ghazale_sds_";
        $input_tables = $wpdb->get_results( "SHOW TABLES LIKE " . "'" . $tables . "%_inputs'", ARRAY_A );
        $field_tables = $wpdb->get_results( "SHOW TABLES LIKE " . "'" . $tables . "%_fields'", ARRAY_A );
        $has_result   = array();
        if ( ! empty( $input_tables ) ) {
            $hidden_field  = array();
            $shown_field   = array();
            $results_array = array();
            foreach ( $input_tables as $input_table ) {
                foreach ( $input_table as $table ) {
                    if ( get_option( 'ghazale_sds_separate_search' ) ) {
                        shortcode_atts( array(
                            'table' => str_replace( array(
                                $tables,
                                '_inputs'
                            ), '', $table )
                        ), $atts );
                    }
                    if ( get_option( 'ghazale_sds_separate_search' ) && str_replace( array(
                            $tables,
                            '_inputs'
                        ), '', $table ) == $atts['table'] ) {

                        $inputs_sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " ORDER BY id ASC";
                        $inputs     = $wpdb->get_results( $inputs_sql, ARRAY_A );
                        if ( trim( $_POST['sds-search-data'] != '' ) ) {
                            $results_sql = "SELECT id,field_id,field_input FROM " . $table . " WHERE field_input COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '" . $_POST['sds-search-data'] . "%' ORDER BY id ASC";
                            $results     = $wpdb->get_results( $results_sql, ARRAY_A );
                            foreach ( $field_tables as $field_table ) {
                                foreach ( $field_table as $field_table_single ) {
                                    if ( $field_table_single == str_replace( "_inputs", "_fields", "$table" ) ) {
                                        $fields_sql = "SELECT id,field_name,field_type,field_hide FROM " . $field_table_single;
                                        $fields     = $wpdb->get_results( $fields_sql, ARRAY_A );

                                        if ( ! empty( $inputs ) ) {

                                            foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                                                $first_id = $field['id'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                                                $last_id = $field['id'];
                                            }
                                            if ( $results ) {

                                                foreach ( $results as $result ) {
                                                    if ( strstr( $result['field_input'], '@' ) != true ) {
                                                        $output            .= "<div id=\"" . $table . "\">";
                                                        $output            .= "<table class = \"table\">";
                                                        $range_initial_sql = 'SELECT id FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE field_id<= ' . $result['field_id'] . ' AND field_id =' . $first_id . ' AND id<= ' . $result['id'] . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
                                                        $range_initial     = $wpdb->get_results( $range_initial_sql, ARRAY_A );
                                                        $range_final_sql   = 'SELECT id FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE field_id>= ' . $result['field_id'] . ' AND field_id =' . $last_id . ' AND id>= ' . $result['id'] . ' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1';
                                                        $range_final       = $wpdb->get_results( $range_final_sql, ARRAY_A );

                                                        $result_range_sql = 'SELECT id,field_id,field_input FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE id BETWEEN ' . $range_initial[0]['id'] . ' and ' . $range_final[0]['id'];
                                                        $result_range     = $wpdb->get_results( $result_range_sql, ARRAY_A );
                                                        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                                                            if ( $field['field_hide'] == "Hide" ) {
                                                                //if the field is hidden don't show anything
                                                                array_push( $hidden_field, $field['id'] );
                                                            } else {
                                                                //otherwise show it on search query
                                                                array_push( $shown_field, $field['field_name'] );
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        foreach ( $result_range as $single_result ) {
                                                            if ( ! in_array( $single_result['field_id'], $hidden_field ) ) {
                                                                array_push( $results_array, $single_result['field_input'] );
                                                            }
                                                        }


                                                        foreach ( $shown_field as $index => $single_field ) {
                                                            $output .= "<tr>";
                                                            if ( $results_array[ $index ] != "" ) {
                                                                $link_or_img = strlen( $results_array[ $index ] ) - 3;
                                                                $jpeg_img    = strlen( $results_array[ $index ] ) - 4;
                                                                if ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], 0, 4 ) === "http" && ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "png" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "jpg" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "pdf" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "bmp" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $jpeg_img, 4 ) == "jpeg" ) ) {
                                                                    $output .= "<th style='text-align: center'>" . $single_field . "</th><td style='text-align: center'><img src='" . $results_array[ $index ] . "' width=\"100\"></td>";
                                                                } elseif ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], 0, 4 ) === "http" && ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "png" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "jpg" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "pdf" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "bmp" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $jpeg_img, 4 ) != "jpeg" ) ) {
                                                                    $output .= "<th style='text-align: center'>" . $single_field . "</th><td style='text-align: center'><a href='" . $results_array[ $index ] . "'>" . $results_array[ $index ] . "</a></td>";
                                                                } else {
                                                                    $output .= "<th style='text-align: center'>" . $single_field . "</th><td style='text-align: center'>" . stripslashes( $results_array[ $index ] ) . "</td>";
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            $output .= "</tr>";

                                                        }
                                                        $output .= "</table>";
                                                        $output .= "</div>";
                                                        unset( $hidden_field );
                                                        $hidden_field = array();
                                                        unset( $shown_field );
                                                        $shown_field = array();
                                                        unset( $results_array );
                                                        $results_array = array();
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                array_push( $has_result, 'Has Result' );
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } elseif ( ! get_option( 'ghazale_sds_separate_search' ) ) {
                        $inputs_sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " ORDER BY id ASC";
                        $inputs     = $wpdb->get_results( $inputs_sql, ARRAY_A );
                        if ( trim( $_POST['sds-search-data'] != '' ) ) {
                            $results_sql = "SELECT id,field_id,field_input FROM " . $table . " WHERE field_input COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '" . $_POST['sds-search-data'] . "%' ORDER BY id ASC";
                            $results     = $wpdb->get_results( $results_sql, ARRAY_A );
                            foreach ( $field_tables as $field_table ) {
                                foreach ( $field_table as $field_table_single ) {
                                    if ( $field_table_single == str_replace( "_inputs", "_fields", "$table" ) ) {
                                        $fields_sql = "SELECT id,field_name,field_type,field_hide FROM " . $field_table_single;
                                        $fields     = $wpdb->get_results( $fields_sql, ARRAY_A );

                                        if ( ! empty( $inputs ) ) {

                                            foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                                                $first_id = $field['id'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                                                $last_id = $field['id'];
                                            }
                                            if ( $results ) {

                                                foreach ( $results as $result ) {
                                                    if ( strstr( $result['field_input'], '@' ) != true ) {
                                                        $output            .= "<div id=\"" . $table . "\">";
                                                        $output            .= "<table class = \"table\">";
                                                        $range_initial_sql = 'SELECT id FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE field_id<= ' . $result['field_id'] . ' AND field_id =' . $first_id . ' AND id<= ' . $result['id'] . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
                                                        $range_initial     = $wpdb->get_results( $range_initial_sql, ARRAY_A );
                                                        $range_final_sql   = 'SELECT id FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE field_id>= ' . $result['field_id'] . ' AND field_id =' . $last_id . ' AND id>= ' . $result['id'] . ' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1';
                                                        $range_final       = $wpdb->get_results( $range_final_sql, ARRAY_A );

                                                        $result_range_sql = 'SELECT id,field_id,field_input FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE id BETWEEN ' . $range_initial[0]['id'] . ' and ' . $range_final[0]['id'];
                                                        $result_range     = $wpdb->get_results( $result_range_sql, ARRAY_A );
                                                        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                                                            if ( $field['field_hide'] == "Hide" ) {
                                                                //if the field is hidden don't show anything
                                                                array_push( $hidden_field, $field['id'] );
                                                            } else {
                                                                //otherwise show it on search query
                                                                array_push( $shown_field, $field['field_name'] );
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        foreach ( $result_range as $single_result ) {
                                                            if ( ! in_array( $single_result['field_id'], $hidden_field ) ) {
                                                                array_push( $results_array, $single_result['field_input'] );
                                                            }
                                                        }


                                                        foreach ( $shown_field as $index => $single_field ) {
                                                            $output .= "<tr>";
                                                            if ( $results_array[ $index ] != "" ) {
                                                                $link_or_img = strlen( $results_array[ $index ] ) - 3;
                                                                $jpeg_img    = strlen( $results_array[ $index ] ) - 4;
                                                                if ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], 0, 4 ) === "http" && ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "png" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "jpg" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "gif" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) == "bmp" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $jpeg_img, 4 ) == "jpeg" ) ) {
                                                                    $output .= "<th style='text-align: center'>" . $single_field . "</th><td style='text-align: center'><img src='" . $results_array[ $index ] . "' width=\"100\"></td>";
                                                                } elseif ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], 0, 4 ) === "http" && ( substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "png" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "jpg" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "gif" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $link_or_img, 3 ) != "bmp" || substr( $results_array[ $index ], $jpeg_img, 4 ) != "jpeg" ) ) {
                                                                    $output .= "<th style='text-align: center'>" . $single_field . "</th><td style='text-align: center'><a href='" . $results_array[ $index ] . "'>" . $results_array[ $index ] . "</a></td>";
                                                                } else {
                                                                    $output .= "<th style='text-align: center'>" . $single_field . "</th><td style='text-align: center'>" . stripslashes( $results_array[ $index ] ) . "</td>";
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            $output .= "</tr>";

                                                        }
                                                        $output .= "</table>";
                                                        $output .= "</div>";
                                                        unset( $hidden_field );
                                                        $hidden_field = array();
                                                        unset( $shown_field );
                                                        $shown_field = array();
                                                        unset( $results_array );
                                                        $results_array = array();
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                array_push( $has_result, 'Has Result' );
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        if ( count( $has_result ) == 0 ) {
            $output .= "<h4>" . __( 'No Result', 'custom-searchable-data-entry-system' ) . "</h4>";
        }

    }

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'sds-search', 'ghazale_sds_front_end_search_field' );

/**
 * loading language file
 */
function ghazale_sds_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'custom-searchable-data-entry-system', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'ghazale_sds_load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

Comment: Can you [minimize your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Rojo i don't know how to solve the code, so i show you here all the code which can help

Comment: Do you receive errors?

Comment: no error, i'll explain every thing... this is a code for a search form which get data from database to the page.. what happen is when i search for 0 it's shows all the results starts with 0 .... what i need is to show 0 only if it exists so i need exat match between the value in the input and database with out showing anything else

Comment: @rojo are you still there ?